# Override Newtonsoft serialization using Generic custom converter

Tags: c#, json.net

I know I can define a custom converter but in that case I have to decorate the class I'd like to serialize using my converter, I want define an overload of the default serialize method in order to personalize the serialization but maintaining it generic (I mean it should work for every type of object)

The goal is to generate a "json" without the main brackets.

Thanks in advance,

Vincenzo.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work too?

```
string json = "{\"Name\":\"Max\"}";
string withoutBrackets = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);
```

Alternative using Regex:

```
string withoutBrackets = Regex.Replace(json, @"(?:^\{)|(?:\}$)",string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your response I already thought your solution but, for my chief reason, I need to avoid transformation after serialization, this is why I need to go inside the serializer in order to avoid to call the methods :   writer.WriteStartObject();  and   writer.WriteEndObject();

Comment: @vincenzogreco often the most simple solution is the one to choose... you have to ask yourself would the result be any different? Implementing custom converters may lead you to the goal but at what cost of complexity? You could simply write an extension method for stripping the outer brackets from a string and can use it everywhere you need to as well...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to decorate a class with the converter, when you are serializing the object you can provide the converter to the serializer and the converter will know what types it can serialize. (On method CanConvert)

Below is a small snippet of code where we use a custom converter DataRowCollectionConverter for converting our collection of data row type objects in a specific way.
DataRowCollectionConverter is a JsonConverter

```
 this.Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result,  DataRowCollectionConverter());;
```

Comment: Hi Angelo thanks for your response but I'd like a generic method while your example is specific.